# CSS only - Swap image and add link

Tags: html, css

This code is what I used to try to swap an image once clicked and then to add another click to the image that is revealed which will direct to a new url. However this should only be active when the revealed image show on the swap.

In relation to the fact that it needs to be done through CSS only is due to the fact that I want to get it working in an email and Javascript is stripped out.

Is this any clearer. Thanks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <style>
            #example-five {
                position: relative;
            }
            #example-five-checkbox {
                display: none;
            }
            #example-five-checkbox:checked + #example-five:after {
                content: '<img src = "https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=Hide" />';
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                background: white;
             }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="checkbox" id="example-five-checkbox" />
        <label id="example-five" for="example-five-checkbox"><img src = "https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=Show" /></label>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to show link when mouse hovers the image? or replace image with link?

Comment: Please update the question with what you have tried for achieving the desired outcome and links to any documentation stating what you tried should work.

Comment: "clicked using CSS only" doesn't make sense

Comment: Protip: CSS in email is far from reliable as well.

Comment: ok just wondering if it is possible to get it working outside of email so that it would be ok for an online version

Comment: any help getting this working would be great, thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can utilize the `:target` pseudo class here.

Position the image containers absolutely in a parent container, positioning to the top left. Give the 2nd image with the external link a `z-index` that would normally cover the first image. Now hide the 2nd image with `display:none`. Add a link from the first image to the id of the 2nd image.

This relies on the 2nd image being big enough to cover the first.

```css
#container {position:relative;}
#image1 {position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:1;
}

#image2 {position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:2;
  display:none;
}

#image2:target {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="image1">
    <a href="#image2"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=Show" /></a>
  </div>
  <div id="image2">
    <a href="//www.google.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=To Goole.." /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```